# How to create a multiline graph with differents labels

Tags: charts, chart.js, line, multiline

I need to create a graph who contains different prices from different sites and not taking at the same moment. Actually I'm using the javascript library chart.js. I want to know if it possible to have on the same date different and the number of the point is different ?

```
    "{
      "site1":[
         {
           "datetime":"2019-01-09 14:43:58",
           "price":"649.99"
         },
         {
           "datetime":"2019-01-09 14:44:17",
           "price":"649.99"
         },
         {
           "datetime":"2019-01-09 15:02:59",
           "price":"649.99"
          },
          {
            "datetime":"2019-01-09 15:05:43",
            "price":"649.99"
          },
          {
            "datetime":"2019-01-09 15:08:52",
            "price":"649.99"
          },
          {
            "datetime":"2019-01-09 15:16:51",
            "price":"649.99"
          }
       ],
       "site2":[
         {
           "datetime":"2019-01-09 15:03:05",
           "price":"0"
         },
         {
           "datetime":"2019-01-09 15:05:52",
           "price":"804.91"
         },
         {
           "datetime":"2019-01-09 15:09:00",
           "price":"804.91"
         },
         {
           "datetime":"2019-01-09 15:16:58",
           "price":"804.91"
         }
       ]
     }"
```

This is a sample of data for the graph.

I'm sorry if my explanation is not simple.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by using the [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). You'll need to remodel your data to fit the required input format; an example of this is in the snippet below using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

It's important to note that Chart.js requires Moment.js for datetime handling. Make sure to include Moment.js before Chart.js, or use the Chart.js [bundled build](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build).

```js
let j = {
    "site1": [{
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 14:43:58",
        "price": "649.99"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 14:44:17",
        "price": "649.99"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 15:02:59",
        "price": "649.99"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 15:05:43",
        "price": "649.99"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 15:08:52",
        "price": "649.99"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 15:16:51",
        "price": "649.99"
      }
    ],
    "site2": [{
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 15:03:05",
        "price": "0"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 15:05:52",
        "price": "804.91"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 15:09:00",
        "price": "804.91"
      },
      {
        "datetime": "2019-01-09 15:16:58",
        "price": "804.91"
      }
    ]
  },
  k = Object.keys(j),
  datasets = [];

// remodel the data so it can be provided direct to Chart.js
k.forEach(function(val) {
  let d = {
    label: val,
    data: []
  };

  j[val].forEach(function(val2) {
    d.data.push({
      x: val2.datetime,
      y: val2.price
    });
  });

  datasets.push(d);
});

// create the chart.
new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using Chart.js + Moment.js when you're plotting a chart against time.

See this below code or fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/goz3jehy/4/

```
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: "site1",
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderColor: 'pink',
        fill: false,
        data: [{
            x: '2019-01-09 14:43:58',
            y: 649.99
          },
          {
            x: '2019-01-09 14:44:17',
            y: 649.99
          },
          {
            x: "2019-01-09 15:02:59",
            y: 649.99
          },
          {
            x: "2019-01-09 15:05:43",
            y: 649.99
          },
          {
            x: "2019-01-09 15:08:52",
            y: 649.99
          },
          {
            x: "2019-01-09 15:16:51",
            y: 700
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        label: "site2",
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        borderColor: 'yellow',
        fill: false,
        data: [{
            x: "2019-01-09 15:03:05",
            y: 0
          },
          {
            x: "2019-01-09 15:05:52",
            y: 804.91
          },
          {
            x: "2019-01-09 15:09:00",
            y: 804.91
          },
          {
            x: "2019-01-09 15:16:58",
            y: 804.91
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {          
        }
      }],
    },
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```